# Does ethnic diversity of the academic staff affect the productivity of the faculty?

Tags: reference-request, diversity, ethnicity

Are there any studies where the effect of ethnic diversity on the productivity studied? If so, what are the criteria?

Do universities with more diversity tend to prepare better publications, or the average salary of alumni is higher than the others?

Comment: Are all universities equal in terms of publications? And will ethnic diversity be the only contributing factor?

Comment: Do you have particular fields in mind?

Comment: There are a variety of studies of the impact of diversity (at least of views and interaction styles) on productivity. Most are within businesses. Whether there are any within university contexts is unknown by me.

Comment: @Buffy not really. I just wondered if such study has been done for any field.

Comment: "Average salary of alumni" probably tells you more about what kind of students *enter* the university - and how ruthless it is in weeding out those who might drag down the averages - than about the quality of the education it provides while they're there.